# can I change version code from apk?

Tags: android

I build an app for android and I already export it to apk, can I change its version code if it's already exported? How can I do that?

I lost the backup code and I only have the update one and need to get back at first one, the only thing I can do is to increase version code from the apk backup and then my app will upgrade (while actually downgrade) automatically

Answer (score 5):

You need to open **apktool.yml** 
from there you can modify the version code
[image]

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use [this link][1] it explains many things over there. I will copy paste it:

Tools:

apktool — tool for reverse engineering Android apk files. In this case we are using to extract files from apk and rebuild.
keytool — Java tool for creating keys/certs, that comes with the JDK.
jarsigner Java tool for signing JAR/APK files, that comes with the JDK.
zipalign — archive alignment tool, that comes with the Android SDK.

Instructions:

1. apktool d my_application.apk
2. Change versionCode in apktool.yml.
3. apktool b my_application
4. keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
5. jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application/dist/my_application.apk alias_name
6. jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs my_application/dist/my_application.apk
7. zipalign -v 4 my_application/dist/my_application.apk my_application/dist/my_application-aligned.apk

But to be honest, i still couldn't manage it, Google Play Store says "ERROR: MIN_SIG_SCHEME_FOR_TARGET_SDK_NOT_MET: Target SDK version 30 requires a minimum of signature scheme v2; the APK is not signed with this or a later signature scheme", so i don't guarrantee you that it will work but you can give it a try.
[1]: https://medium.com/@sandeepcirusanagunla/decompile-and-recompile-an-android-apk-using-apktool-3d84c2055a82

Comment: you forgot to mention that the new APK is stored in `my_application/dist/my_application.apk'

Answer (score 0):

you can do the followings

- decompile the apk
- update the versioncode in manifest
- again recompile the apk

you can use [apktool](https://code.google.com/p/android-apktool/)

Comment: pls check this link to know about android reverse engineering .. https://kkinder.com/2011/11/27/so-you-want-to-reverse-engineer-an-android-app-apk/

Comment: Tried that, but decompiled apk file has no version info. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37479412/why-my-apks-androidmanifest-xml-has-no-version-information

Answer (score 0):

It's simple: 
You need to,

- Download the apk (Under **release management** on **google play
  console** and go to **Artifact Library**)
- Decompile the apk
- Update the versioncode in manifest
- Recompile the apk

Comment: this is a non-answer